# Most efficient way to allow only one number after the decimal

Tags: php

I have a data set returned from yahoo finance api that is formatted like the following:

```
167.3B
97.719B
1.322B
973.4M
77.8M
```

I want to only allow one digit after the decimal. I can think of a number of ways to do it but they all seem somewhat cumbersome. Anyone know a best practice?

Comment: I also need to retain the last letter character, whether it be a B or an M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$letter = substr($number, -1);
$output = round($number, 1) . $letter;
```

This will round to the nearest 10th of an integer

You could do:

```
round(floor($number)*10)/10
```

If $number equaled 5.69 that would return 5.6, but rounding will be more accurate and is considered the best practice.

Comment: I think you need to re-order your second option a bit.

Comment: sure but what about the process of removing the letter character, retaining it, then placing it back on...This is where it got cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
number_format($number, 1)
```

Comment: this will add commas on numbers greater than 999